# Using Lagrange multipliers to find volume of a cone

Tags: calculus

Using the method of Lagrange multipliers (or otherwise) find the maximum possible volume of a (right circular) cone which can be inscribed in a sphere of radius a.

Comment: It is custom on math.stackexchange to state what you have tried, your thoughts on the problem, or where are you stuck in the problem.

Comment: Hi! Sorry but the problem is I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

$\textit{Hint}$:  Use the formula $V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$, and slice the cone vertically down the middle to produce a triangle which contains a right triangle with sides of length $r$ and $h-a$ and a hypotenuse of length $a$.

Now use the Pythagorean Theorem to express $r^2$ in terms of $h$.